# aptana full screen & escape key on osx

Tags: aptana3

I usually put my Aptana (Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.3.1.201212171919) window in full screen on OSX. One intensely annoying feature is that it leaves full screen as soon as you hit escape. I use this key a lot, often indadvertedly. None of the other applications I have full screen seem to behave like this (eclipse, iterm, chrome).

I googled for it and found out that there is something called ToggleFullScreenEscapeHandler in aptana which seems like it is designed to do exactly the wrong thing here.

I checked the key preferences and there is no option for anything to do with fullscreen and the escape button was actually bound to hiding the find screen.

So how do you turn this thing off?

Personally, I think it is kind of weird to have any application global function bound to escape at all given how often it is used in a context specific way.

Comment: I agree. So annoying!